# Nodejs is not able to work after creating different routing files

Tags: node.js, routes

I have an error while running my index.js file after separating the code into different files.
I'm running index.js in the terminal in the right folder as required.

This is my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Joi = require("joi");
const genres = require("./routes/genres");
const home = require("./routes/home");

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/genres", genres);
app.use("/api/home", home);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`you are listening to port ${port}`));
```

This is my genres file for routing:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
.
.
.My routing settings 
. 
.
module.exports = router;
```

This is the error that I get in vs code after running index.js via terminal:

[image]

Will be glad to get any assistance.

Comment: Missing closing bracket; const genres = require('./routes/genres');

Comment: Ups I corrected it by accident  ;-)

Comment: Hi Mario,

Thank you for investing time in answering my question. 
This is not the problem, after adding the closing bracket  I'm still getting the same error. /:

Comment: @cherful can you elaborate, please. 
I'm so frustrated. I didn't find any syntax error /:

Comment: cd to your project directory, then try to run the index.js

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```
const genres = require("./routes/genres")(app);
const home = require("./routes/home")(app);

app.use("/api/genres", genres);
app.use("/api/home", home);
```

genre.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router

  .get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.send('get data');
  })

 .post('/add', async (req, res) => {
    res.send('get data');
  })

module.exports = router;
```